# Iterate over pandas dataframe using value in separate dataframe, filtered by shared column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in the following form:

df1

| id | name | df2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | foo | template_x |
| two | bar | template_y |
| three | baz | template_z |

df2

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| template_x | aaa | zzz |
| template_x | bbb | yyy |
| template_y | ccc | xxx |
| template_y | ddd | www |
| template_z | eee | vvv |
| template_z | fff | uuu |

For each value in `df1` where `df2_id` == `df2.id`, I'd like to iterate over `df2` and append the value of `df1.id` to `name` and `value` in each row to get:

df3

| id | concat_name | concat_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| template_x | aaa_one | zzz_one |
| template_x | bbb_one | yyy_one |
| template_y | ccc_two | xxx_two |
| template_y | ddd_two | www_two |
| template_z | eee_three | vvv_three |
| template_z | fff_three | uuu_three |

Constraints/caveats:

- All relevant values are strings, no integers.
- Sometimes `df2.value` is empty, and I would like to keep it empty.

My approach was to use nested for loop with `df.iterrows`, but it's giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can `merge` the DataFrames and add relevant columns together:

```
merged = df1[['id','df2_id']].merge(df2, left_on='df2_id', right_on='id', suffixes=('_',''))
merged['name'] += '_' + merged['id_']
merged['value'] += '_' + merged['id_']
merged = merged.drop(columns=['id_', 'df2_id']).rename(columns={'name':'concat_name', 'value':'concat_val'})
```

Output:

```
           id concat_name concat_val
0  template_x     aaa_one    zzz_one
1  template_x     bbb_one    yyy_one
2  template_y     ccc_two    xxx_two
3  template_y     ddd_two    www_two
4  template_z   eee_three  vvv_three
5  template_z   fff_three  uuu_three
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty sleek one-liner:

```
df2[['name', 'value']] = df2[['name', 'value']].T.add('_' + df1.set_index('df2_id').loc[df2['id'], 'id'].reset_index(drop=True)).T
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
           id       name      value
0  template_x    aaa_one    zzz_one
1  template_x    bbb_one    yyy_one
2  template_y    ccc_two    xxx_two
3  template_y    ddd_two    www_two
4  template_z  eee_three  vvv_three
5  template_z  fff_three  uuu_three
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. And also thanks for the help with formatting.